# Almacenar varias variables de un formulario y mostrarlas en pantalla

Tags: javascript, formularios, variables, alert

Mi pregunta es muy básica (soy nueva en esto) pero no consigo que mi función funcione.
Necesito almacenar tres datos introducidos por el usuario y que después al pulsar un botón mostrar esos datos a través de alert. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<form action="./procesarFormulario.php" name="registros">
Registro: <input type="text" id="num 1" />
Código: <input type="text" id="num 2" />
Almacén: <input type="text" id="num3" />

<button type= "button" onclick="mostrar();">Mostrar Código</button>
</form>

    function mostrar(){
var uno = document.getElementById("num1").value;
var dos = document.getElementById("num2").value;
var tres = document.getElementById("num3").value;
alert("Los datos introducidos son: "+uno+"-"+dos+"-"+tres+);
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano! Creo q mi fallo está en que las variables no se almacenan en ningún lado, también probé con la opcion console.log() pero sigue sin funcionar porque pienso que solo almacena un dato.

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis, en el HTML tus ID tienen espacios en blanco en sus nombres y luego en el JS cuando los recuperas están sin espacios en blanco, prueba quitando dichos espacios en tu HTML para que coincidan

Answer (score 1):

el problema que veo es que estas poniendo mal las variables, (el id, num 1 deberia ser num1) todo junto. debe ser igual que el id. Además en el alert, debes suprimir el + del valor tres antes del parentesis. "+tres);"
Quedando el código así.

```html
<doctype!>
<head>
<script>
function mostrar(){
    var uno = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var dos = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var tres = document.getElementById("num3").value;
    alert("Los datos introducidos son: "+uno+"-"+dos+"-"+tres);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" name="registros">
Registro: <input type="text" id="num1" />
Código: <input type="text" id="num2" />
Almacén: <input type="text" id="num3" />
<button type= "button" onclick="mostrar();">Mostrar Código</button>
</form>

</body>
```

La consola del Explorador de Chrome o cualquier navegador te puede ayudar a resolver este tipo de errores. Un saludo

Comment: Muchiisimas gracias era solo eso!!! ;D